# How to draw a Finite state machine

Tags: erlang, fsm

How to draw a Finite state machine according this code

```
machine() ->
 receive
 {add, P} -> receive {X, Y} -> P!(X + Y), machine() end;
 {sub, P} -> receive {X, Y} -> P!(X - Y), machine() end
 end.
```

Answer (score 0):

In an erlang implementation of an fsm:

1. A recursive function is a `state`, so your fsm has only one state, i.e. `machine`, which doesn't even sound like a state name.  Rather, "machine" or "calculator" would be a more appropriate name for the fsm (module).
2. A received message is an `event`.
3. An `action` is a function that is called in response to an event.

If you look at [LYSE](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/finite-state-machines), your fsm is essentially the cat.  In your case, there are two paths back to the original state, and each path requires two events.  So, something like this:

[image]

But, perhaps your calculator fsm should look more like this:

```
-module(calc).
-compile(export_all).

selection() ->
    receive
        add -> addition();
        sub -> subtraction();
        _Other   -> selection()
    end.

addition() ->
    receive 
        {X, Y} -> 
            display("~w + ~w = ~w", [X, Y, X+Y]),
            selection();
        _Other -> addition()
    end.

subtraction() ->
    receive 
        {X, Y} -> 
            display("~w - ~w = ~w", [X, Y, X-Y]),
            selection();
        _Other -> subtraction()
    end.

display(Str, Args) ->
    io:format(Str ++ "~n", Args).
```

In this fsm, there are three `states`:

1. selection  (select the operation)
2. addition
3. subtraction

The `selection state` has two events:

1. `add`
2. `sub`

The `addition/subtraction states` have one event:

1. `{X, Y}`

The addition/subtraction states both execute the display() `action` before transitioning back to the selection() state.